# Android app level build.gradle giving Error : httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, apache-httpcomponents

In one of my old project, I am getting this error/suggestion in my app level build.gradle file:

> httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

It seems the error is because of the dependency `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.12`

I tried to find the solution over the internet. Tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46989310/8874958) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56150759/8874958) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54355038/8874958) but nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try excluding the `httpclient` from it.   Something like this - `implementation  ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.12') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}`

Comment: I already tried it but it is used in my network operations, so network classes are giving errors after doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13"` and excluding `group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'`

Check this:

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.12') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13"
```

Comment: I've done what you posted but it cancels some of my needed classes and gives them errors